# Ubuntu 14.04 / Chromecast / Desktop casting / no audio

Tags: 14.04, sound, google-chrome, chromium, chromecast

I am trying to cast a window / desktop from Ubuntu 14.04 to Chromecast. I have tried both last versions of Chromium (v53.0.2785.143) and Chrome (54.0.2840.100). Both can cast video but none cast audio. Tab casting works perfectly for both.

After some internet research I found some solutions. Basically changing the flags to enable/disable:
chrome://flags/#media-router
chrome://flags/#disable-audio-support-for-desktop-share

However, this has not worked for me. After trying, I get an error in Chrome saying that no system audio can be delivered for this device.

Also I do not have the flag chrome://flags/#try-supported-channel-layouts which is proposed in other solutions.

Do you have any other ideas?